# Java, Raspbian Jessie May 26, how to setup windows fonts

Tags: java, windows, fonts, raspbian

I developed a GUI application with JAVA swing components and run it on Windows. When running the same application on Raspbian Jessie the font and size is different. 
I found many solutions to solve this for other Linux implementation. I tried those. Mainly I failed due to different setup file names etc with the new "Jessie" implementation dated 26th of May 2016.
Could anyone please guide me to a proper installation procedure to get the same font appearance on Jessie as on my Windows desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Just to finalise this. As I did not get an answer, I decided to change all fonts in my application to those available in both Windows and Linux.